# мультизагрузка изображений в Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Как сделать мультизагрузку изображений в Active Admin с возможностью их удаления и изменения? Использую гем jquery-fileupload-rails для загрузки большого количества изображений, сейчас посмотреть какие файлы я загружаю и сразу же удалить их я не могу(хотя сам jQuery-File-Upload это вроде как позволяется сделать). Хотелось бы сделать что-то вроде этого https://youtu.be/x23aIQPa-DY?t=666 но с возможностью подружить это с Active Admin.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте gem activeadmin-dropzone https://github.com/farpostdesign/activeadmin-dropzone

Он интегрирует библиотеку dropzone.js в панель администратора Active Admin, которая позволяет drag-n-drop-ом загружать большое количество файлом, менять их названия, удалять и т.п.

Но стоит обратить внимание, что он работает с двумя моделями, абстрактно выражаясь, с моделью-контейнером и моделью-изображением. Например, Post и Photo соответственно. Поддерживается загрузка изображений для еще не сохраненного контейнера.

По установке, в модель-изображение добавляется:

```
class Image
    dropzone_item container_id: :page_id
end
```

Но выводить dropzone мы будем для модели-контейнера таким образом:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :images, as: :dropzone
  end
end
```

Также надо установить permit_params:

```
permit_params :title,
            :annotation,
            :description,
            ...,
            image_ids: [], # for model Image
            images_attributes: [:id, :title, :position, :_destroy] # for model Image
```

И `accepts_nested_attributes_for :images` для модели-контейнера.

А также статику для плагина dropzone в файлы active_admin.js и active_admin.css:

```
//= require activeadmin-dropzone
```

Он сейчас у нас на поддержке, работает в продакшене успешно. Напишите на почту alexey2142@mail.ru, если возникнут трудности в установке, это поможет нам сделать этот гем лучше и подкорректировать инструкции по установке.